# Adding timingFunction to SCNAction breaks action completion handler

Tags: ios, animation, scenekit, scnnode

I have a strange situation. I'm trying to run animation and I'm waiting for completion handler. Everything works fine until I define timingFunction. After that sometimes completionHandler is not called at all. And my animation stuck on last frame.

```
CGFloat rotations = times * 2.0;
CGFloat zoomLevel = COIN_MOVE_UP;
SCNAction* rotate = [SCNAction rotateByX:M_PI_2 y:0 z:0 duration:2.0 / (rotations + 1)];
NSUInteger swaps = rotations / 2;
SCNAction* rotateSequence = [SCNAction repeatAction:rotate count:2];
SCNAction* coinRotate = [SCNAction repeatAction:rotateSequence count:swaps];
SCNAction* coinRotateAction = [SCNAction sequence:@[coinRotate, rotate]];

SCNAction* coinMoveUpAction = [SCNAction moveByX:0 y:-zoomLevel z:0 duration:1];
SCNAction* coinMoveDownAction = [SCNAction moveByX:0 y:zoomLevel z:0 duration:1];

SCNAction* coinMoveAction = [SCNAction sequence:@[coinMoveUpAction, coinMoveDownAction]];
SCNAction* coinRotateY = [SCNAction rotateByX:0 y:M_PI z:0 duration:2];
SCNAction* fullGroup = [SCNAction group:@[coinRotateAction, coinMoveAction, coinRotateY]];
[fullGroup setTimingFunction:^(float time){
    return time;
}];

[self.coinNode runAction:fullGroup completionHandler:^{
    // completion is not called sometimes when timingFunction is efined
}];
```

Do you have any idea how to fix that?

P.S.
I've implemented:

```
-(void)renderer:(id<SCNSceneRenderer>)renderer didApplyAnimationsAtTime:(NSTimeInterval)time{

}
```

and without timing function this method stop being called when animation is finished but when timig function is present sometimes animation is running till its end but completion handler is not called and didApplyAnimationsAtTime: is still being called. So maybe somehow this animation is still running even after reaching end state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I was able to fix this issue by using

```
+ (SCNAction *)customActionWithDuration:(NSTimeInterval)seconds actionBlock:(void (^)(SCNNode *node, CGFloat elapsedTime))block;
```

so I removed all timing functions and reimplemented them as block:

```
CGFloat angle = M_PI_2;
void (^block)(SCNNode * _Nonnull node, CGFloat elapsedTime) = ^(SCNNode * _Nonnull node, CGFloat elapsedTime) {
    CGFloat progress = elapsedTime / duration;
    CGFloat realTime = pow(progress, 6); // here I apply timing
    node.eulerAngles = SCNVector3Make(initialVector.x + (angle * realTime), initialVector.y, initialVector.z);
    node.position = SCNVector3Make(node.position.x, cos(angle * realTime) * 5, sin(angle * realTime) * 5);
};
```

This way I don't have any problems with completion handler that are not called and I still can adjust timing for my animations :)